# super python class itself have any meaning?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

see python code which super function point to class itself, did this function is necessary? If comment the line(or delete, if you like :) ), the result dont change. so what the line actually do?

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self, id):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.id=id
```

Comment: Depends on what the superclass's `__init__()` does. This is a place where the documentation will help you much more than experimentation does. (Really, I'd argue that that's true more often than not: if you don't read the documentation, you don't know which experiments will be useful or informative).

Comment: Expanding on what Charles said, you should read the documentation for the Python language AND for the external libraries that you use AND the codebase that you are working on.  And also tutorials, etcetera if the documentation is too hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the superclass is `object`, whose `__init__` doesn't really do much. If `A` had a nontrivial superclass, then it could make a big difference.

```
class Superclass:
  def __init__(self):
    # Super important initialization happens here
    ...

class A(Superclass):
  def __init__(self):
    super(A, self).__init__()
    ...
```

In this case, the super call very much *does* matter, for `Superclass.__init__` will not otherwise be called.

By the way, the 2-argument form of `super` is for advanced use cases or code written over ten years ago for an ancient version of Python. For most use cases (including this one), `super().__init__()` with no explicit arguments suffices and is much cleaner.